# How to choose a column as user input and pass it into database statement?

Tags: python, sql

```py
def database_delete_row(column, element):
    conn, cur = Connect.database_connection()
    try:
        cur.execute("DELETE FROM feathers WHERE %s = %s", (column, element))
        # cur.execute("DELETE FROM feathers WHERE name_GER = %s", (element, ))
        conn.commit()
        if cur.rowcount > 0:
            return "Data successfully deleted!"
        else:
            return "There is no such record!"
    except mariadb.Error:
        return "Deletion failed!"
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

I've a problem with my delete statement. I want to make choose the user the column with using a form in html. Anyway hardcoding a column's name works well (see 2nd statement). Passing it in as parameter still just doesn't work as expected.

Comment: you've used `cursor.execute('...%s',(...,))` instead of `cursor.execute('...?',(...,))`

Comment: Tried it but replacing %s with ? doesn't work either. %s always worked fine so far. Except in that one case.